# Pytorch: Updating numpy array not updating the corresponding tensor

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

When I run the following code,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(3)
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
np.add(a, 1, out=a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Both a and b are 2s.

However, When I run:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(3)
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
a = a+1
print(a)
print(b)
```

b remains as 1s while a has been updated to 2s.

Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes. the `a` created by `a=a+1` is a new array, without any connection to the `a` that was used to create `b`.  That doesn't update `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as [@hpaulj pointed out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370286/pytorch-updating-numpy-array-not-updating-the-corresponding-tensor/48370488#comment83727462_48370286), the operation

```
a = a + 1
```

creates copy of the original array `a` and adds 1 using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html). And after addition, since we assign it to `a`, so `a` gets updated to the result of addition operation. But, `b` still shares the memory of the original array `a` (i.e. the array `a` that was created before updation.)

So, we see result like this:

```
In [75]: a = np.ones(3)
    ...: b = torch.from_numpy(a)
    ...: a = a+1     # <========= creates copy of `a` and modifies it
    ...: print(a)
    ...: print(b)
    ...: 
[ 2.  2.  2.]

 1
 1
 1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 3]
```

---

But, see what happens when you rather do:

```
In [72]: a = np.ones(3)
    ...: b = torch.from_numpy(a)
    ...: a += 1      # <========== in-place modification of `a`
    ...: print(a)
    ...: print(b)
    ...:

[ 2.  2.  2.]

 2
 2
 2
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 3]
```

Observe how the `+=` operation is making modification to the original array **in-place** whereas `somearr = somearr + 1` creates *copy of the array* `somearray` and then makes modification to it.